# rsyslogd using 197% CPU for the past few days

Tags: 11.04, server, cpu-load, rsyslog

I'm running Natty server on the rackspace cloud and rsyslogd as been churning away usin 197% CPU (quad core machine I believe) for the past few days. Is there anything I can do to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old now but I had this issue on a Virtual private server I am running. It was Ubuntu server and I believe it was 10.10.

I found this page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/rsyslog/+bug/523610

And it suggested to me a problem with the kernel so changed it to use the latest *(through a web interface, the company is running Xen.)* and that solved my problem.

This happened back in July 2011 (a couple of months ago) and I can't remember which version of the kernel I was using but now I'm using version 3.0.0...

Comment: Yeah, this turned out to be the problem. I ended up ditching the server and using Debian instead.

Answer (score 5):

On OpenVZ, rsyslog has a tendency to use 100%+ CPU. The following commands would fix the problem:

```
service rsyslog stop
sed -i -e 's/^\$ModLoad imklog/#\$ModLoad imklog/g' /etc/rsyslog.conf
service rsyslog start
```

Comment: Seems that a fix for this specific bug is on its way. See also the related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1366829

Answer (score 3):

Jesse my go-to "WTF?" debugging method for something like this is strace.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit these:

To see what its doing in real time:

```
sudo strace -p `pidof rsyslogd`
```

To see a summary of where it has been spending its time:

```
sudo strace -c -p `pidof rsyslogd`
```

There are some useful flags to these that will change their output some. `man strace` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug report (that `rsyslogd` is not behaving as expected), please can you report it to the bug-tracker so that it can be tracked down and investigated with your help:

- [launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+filebug](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+filebug?field.title=rsyslog+using+197-percent+CPU+for+four+days)